# If an identity in the language of rings holds for all fields, does it necessarily hold for all commutative rings?

Tags: logic, commutative-algebra, field-theory

It is weirdly difficult to find new identities for ring theory (other than commutativity) that make it more like field theory. This motivates my:

**Question.** If an identity in the language of rings holds for all fields, does it necessarily hold for all commutative rings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. In fact, we don't even need to know it in all fields – it suffices to know it in, say, the rational function field $\mathbb{Q} (X_1, X_2, \ldots)$.

Indeed, let $f (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ and $g (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ be terms in the language of rings, with variables drawn from $X_1, \ldots, X_n$. Then they are provably equal if and only if they denote the same element of $\mathbb{Z} [X_1, \ldots, X_n]$. (Use the universal property of polynomial rings.) Now use the existence of a ring embedding $\mathbb{Z} [X_1, \ldots, X_n] \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q} (X_1, X_2, \ldots)$.

Comment: Actually this is a very useful method - not only in logic. For example, Cramer's rule may be reduced to the case of fields, etc.